# How do I take a file a submit it as blob into my db using java servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a post method that takes a Blob as one of its parameters.
My jsp has this

```
<input type='file' class='form-control' name ='receipt'/>
```

In my Servlet I have this

```
     */
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
    if(req.getParameterMap().containsKey("receipt")){
//      String receipt = req.getParameter("receipt");
        Part receipt =req.getPart("receipt");
        System.out.println("reciept: " + receipt);
        return;
}
```

receipt returns null for me.
I need to convert receipt to a blob.
I'm using `import javax.servlet.http.Part;`
and javax-servlet version 3.1

Comment: assuming that your <input type="file"> is inside the<form>,try adding multiple file input type and  get whole Collection of the parts and see if you are getting any part at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Servlet 3.0 or later then before using `HttpServletRequest#getParts()` method , you must annotate your servlet with `@MultipartConfig`.
I believe you are missing @MultipartConfig tag in your servlet class

**@MultipartConfig**  annotation must be used to indicate that servlet or a form is receiving the Multi Part request from the client.